# Адаптивный фон с absolute

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Собственно нужно чтобы картинка фона бралась из html кода а не бэкграундом из css, как сделать её адаптивной?
Пытался давать абсолютное позиционирование, но ничего не получилось.
Делал так:

```
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
```

В общем делаю лэндинг, сделал адаптивный бэкграунд в css, всё было нормально, но нужно было чтобы картинку можно было менять в html коде.

Comment: это вариант ? http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/dXpdLv?editors=110

Comment: @МаксимЛенский норм, удалил фиддл.

Comment: @Alex78191  наверно удалил - давно это было уже

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего менять картинку в бекграунде через инлайн-стили.

```html
<div style="background-image: url('path');"></div>
```